# Query with multiple IN clause on multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I have this table:

```
    | ID | idService |
    | 1  |     5     |
    | 1  |     10    |
    | 2  |     5     |
    | 2  |     15    |
    | 3  |     5     |
    | 3  |     20    |
    | 4  |     5     |
    | 4  |     25    |
```

I'd like to be able to select all the clients(ID) where the product 5 is present with at least one of the other products (10, 15, 20, 25).

I'm able to do it for one of those combinations with the query:

`SELECT ID FROM table WHERE idService IN (5,10) GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idService) = 2`

However, if I add the other conditions in this query, I will get all the clients that have at least two of the products, doesn't matter if it's 5 with 10 or 10 with 20.

`SELECT ID FROM table WHERE idService IN (5,10) OR idService IN (5,15) OR idService IN (5,20) OR idService IN (5,25) GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT idService) = 2`

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the IN clauses or replace them to get only the clients with one of the four valid combinations.

Edit:

I've been able to make the query work using a subquery.

`SELECT ID FROM table WHERE ID IN ( SELECT ID FROM table WHERE idService =5) AND ( idService =10 OR idService =15 OR idService =20 OR idService =25 ) GROUP BY idSPOrder`

Answer (score 3):

```
select distinct ID from table t1
where (select count(*) from table where ID = t1.ID group by ID) >=2
and (select count(*) from table where Idservice = 5 and ID = t1.ID group by ID) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select Id 
from Table T
where exists (select 1 from Table where Id = T.Id AND idService = 5)
group by Id
having count(*) >= 2
```

Comment: Won't this give me the clients with the service 5 only? I don't see where I will specify that it needs to be with one of the other 4 services.

Comment: The Where clause says "get me Ids that have service 5" the group by says "group them together", the "having count(*) > = 2" part says "make sure it has more than 1" which here would mean "5 and at least 1 more".  Run it and you should get the correct result.

Comment: Oh I get it. I should've probably specified that I have other products than the ones I listed above. It would work fine if I only had the products listed in the table. My bad for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
select table.id from table, 
(select id from table where idservice != 5 group by id)t 
where idservice = 5 and table.id = t.id
```

Comment: It is a join. First table here is 'table' and second table is that nested select query with alias 't'. Join condition is table.id = t.id.